# Admob - Clicking on Native Ads does not work

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to display ads in the Recycler view.

The ad itself is displayed correctly, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

My code for displaying ad:

```
class AdViewHolder(val binding: NativeAdViewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind() {

            val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(binding.root.context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                .forNativeAd { ad : NativeAd ->
                    with(binding) {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(ad.icon?.drawable)
                        titleTextView.text = ad.headline
                        ratingBar.rating = ad.starRating?.toFloat() ?: 0f
                        storeTextView.text = ad.store
                        actionButton.text = ad.callToAction
                        root.setNativeAd(ad)
                        root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                        Napier.d("Ad Error: $adError")
                    }
                })
                .build()

            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    }
```

My xml file
native_ad_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/route_item_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

I have tried to add method:

```
actionButton.setOnClickListener {
    ad.performClick(Bundle())
}
```

But nothing changes

Comment: Are you trying to automate/fake the clicks on the Ad?

Comment: No, I just don't know how to create an ad properly so that the click works.

Comment: You should not use `ad.performClick` as that would be counted against ad fraud. Use test ads & try clicking on the Ads which is safe. See docs: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced#kotlin

Comment: I didn't use this method at first. But nothing happened when I clicked on an ad. After that, I tried to add this method, but nothing changed. Clicking still doesn't work.

Comment: The docs say that I need to call the setNativeAd method to handle clicks.
But I use this method, and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I needed to add this line of code

```
(root as NativeAdView).callToActionView = root
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).